# Display content of Custom fields on child-pages list

Tags: php, custom-fields

I try to display content of custom field on list of sub pages(thumbnail+content+Book now image+custom filds content), my name of custom field is "krotkie-info", this is my code, which display list of suppages (in page.php):

```
<?php
       $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');    ?>
        <?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>

         <div class="child-thumb">
         <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">
         <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>

           <?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>
        </a>
        <?php the_meta('krotkie-info'); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>"><img src="http://wanderer.ventostudio.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/booknow.jpg"></a>

         </div>
<?php endforeach; endif;
?>
```

Here is my beta online version [My page](http://wanderer.ventostudio.eu/mountain-cycling/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php the_meta('krotkie-info',$pageChild->ID); ?>
```